# Attach (show/hide text) dynamically and when clicked show/hide a fieldset below

Tags: jquery, append, toggle, show-hide

I want to attach (show/hide text) dynamically to a span and when clicked on that particular text, i want to have show/hide effect on a fieldset below.
I acheived the task of having show/hide text appended to span. But the problem arises when i click on that text. Nothing happens except the text beside span gets changed.

HTML:

```
<span>Store Dropdown</span>
<fieldset id="fieldset-store" class="showHide">
    <legend>Choose by item:</legend>
    <label for="prodtype">Type:</label>
    <select name="prodtype" id="prodtype">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose type</option>                  
        <option value="1"> Sample1</option>
        <option value="2"> Sample2</option>
        <option value="3"> Sample3</option>
        <option value="4"> Sample4</option>
    </select> 
    <label for="brandtype">of:</label>
    <select name="brandtype" id="brandtype">                
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose brand</option>                 
        <option value="1"> Brand1</option>
        <option value="2"> Brand2</option>
        <option value="3"> Brand3</option>
        <option value="4"> Brand4</option>
    </select>
    <label for="prodprice">Price:</label> <input id="prodprice" name="prodprice" value="" type="text">
</fieldset>
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showHide").prev().append(' <a href="#" class="showHideLink">Show</a>');
    $(".showHide").hide();
    $('a.showHideLink').click(function() {
        if ($(this).html()=='Show')
            $(this).html('Hide');
        else 
            $(this).html('Show');
        $(this).next().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Pls suggest me what changes i need to make. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".showHide").prev().append(' <a href="#" class="showHideLink">Show</a>');
            $(".showHide").hide();
            $('a.showHideLink').click(function() {
                if ($(this).html()=='Show')
                        $(this).html('Hide');
                else
                        $(this).html('Show');
                $(".showHide").toggle('slow');
                return false;
            });
        });
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".showHide").prev().append(' <a href="#" class="showHideLink">Show</a>');
                $(".showHide").hide();
                $('a.showHideLink').click(function() {
                    if ($(this).html()=='Show')
                            $(this).html('Hide');
                    else
                            $(this).html('Show');
                    $(this).parent().next().toggle('slow');
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

Comment: it worked but i would like to know why it didn't work when i tried using ".next()"

Comment: You have appended the anchor tag inside the span and this has no next element.

Comment: if you have specified '$(this).parent().next().toggle('slow');' then it would have worked.